# coluna não obedece ao comando where de um update

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update, where

estou com um problema. No momento que faço um update, quando eu uso o where somente a linha com o codigo informado é atualizado. porem o campo descricao que eu informo, o seu conteudo é replicado para todas as linhas do banco essa é a unica coluna que isso ocorre. Estou usando o php com o codeigniter

**Segue o form:**

```
            <h3> Descrição:</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="descricao" id="texto">
                    <?php echo $evento[0]->cal_descricao ?>  
                </textarea>
            </div>
```

**Segue a funcao de atualizar:**

```
public function editar($id) {
    $data['cal_descricao'] = $this->input->post('descricao');
    $this->db->set('cal_descricao', $this->input->post('descricao'));
    $this->db->set('cal_titulo', $this->input->post('titulo'));
    $this->db->set('cal_estado', $this->input->post('estado'));
    $this->db->set('cal_pais', $this->input->post('pais'));
    $this->db->set('cal_dataEvento', $this->input->post('inicio'));
    $this->db->set('cal_dataTermino', $this->input->post('termino'));
    $this->db->set('cal_modalidades', $this->input->post('modalidades'));
    $this->db->where('cal_cod', $id);
    $this->db->update('v1_calendario');
    if ($this->db->update('calendario', $data)) {           
        $this->load->view('calendario/index');
        redirect('calendario/index');
    } else {
        redirect('calendario/index');
    }
}
```

**Saida html da tabela:**

```
 <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Evelinsss</td>
                    <td><p>vida</p></td>
                    <td>RJ Brazil</td>
                    <td>2016-06-05</td>
                    <td>2016-06-20</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td><a href="http://localhost:8080/WAS/site/controle/calendario/atualizar/1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Atualizar</button>
                        </a>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>Evelin</td>
                    <td><p>vida</p>
```

RJ Brazil
                        2016-06-05
                        2016-06-20
                        27
                        
                            
                                [Atualizar](http://localhost:8080/WAS/site/controle/calendario/atualizar/2)

A atualização da linha somente o titulo da linha um foi modificado, mas a descricao (resultado: vida), ocorre na linha de baixo tambem.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver! o  problema era o update antes do if:

```
 public function editar($id) {
    $data['cal_descricao'] = $this->input->post('descricao');
    $this->db->set('cal_descricao', $this->input->post('descricao'));
    $this->db->set('cal_titulo', $this->input->post('titulo'));
    $this->db->set('cal_estado', $this->input->post('estado'));
    $this->db->set('cal_pais', $this->input->post('pais'));
    $this->db->set('cal_dataEvento', $this->input->post('inicio'));
    $this->db->set('cal_dataTermino', $this->input->post('termino'));
    $this->db->set('cal_modalidades', $this->input->post('modalidades'));
    $this->db->where('cal_cod', $id);
    //        $this->db->update('v1_calendario'); - Removi essa linha
    if ($this->db->update('calendario', $data)) {           
        $this->load->view('calendario/index');
        redirect('calendario/index');
    } else {
        redirect('calendario/index');
    }
}
```